# R "by" function discovering its category?

Tags: r, tapply

Can a function called in **by** detect its factor level?

```
by(d, as.factor(d$x1), function(d) cat("Your current factor level is ", ...))
```

I understand that in this case, `...` could be `head(d$x1,1)`, but this limits the generality to the function knowing **x1**.

I looked at the tapply code, but there it does not seem to be passed on. The docs for `by` state that it is a wrapper for `tapply`; but typing `by` shows that it seems to be beneath the R source layer (in `namespace:base`), while `tapply` is above. I guess it can cross up again, or it may just be a logical wrapper, not in terms of implementation.

Comment: This is on the verge of being incoherent. Too many pronouns without clear antecedents, perhaps. The code for `by.default` is not hidden. The fact that it is in the base package doesn't seem relevant. The definition for "cross up" is not clear to this reasonably well-educated English-speaker. I suspect the answer to the question is "no". The object delivered to the function is not likely to conatin the grouping factor level in either its numeric or character form. But looking at the code I would imagine that you could get useful information by at the `call` leaf of the returned list.

Comment: I think the basic answer is 'no'. The `FUN=` function in `by` is not aware of the current state of the variable used to split the input `data`. You might want to investigate `data.table` and its `.BY` identifier, which is quite neat.

Comment: You can also hack together a version of `by()` that allows you to access the grouping variable `spl` - e.g. `Map(function(SD,u) data.frame(SD,id=u), split(data, spl), sort(unique(spl)))`